# Asp.net 5 - Docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I'm about to lose my head ;-)
I've tried all tutorials I can find on running ASP.NET 5 using Docker in Linux.
It won't work....
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 no matter what I do I always get :

`mountpoint for devices not ready.`

For some Dockerfile setup I'll get this message in build for other configuration I'll get it on run.
There is no point to shave my Dockerfile because I had tens of them.
I'm using Windows 10 Hyper-V for the virualization

Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-rc1-final
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["dnu", "restore"]
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dnx","-p", "project.json",  "kestrel"]
```

Build - `docker build -t dev3 .`

Run - `docker run -t -d -p 87:5000 dev3`

Docker Install - `apt-get install docker.io`

Comment: Can you post your `Dockerfile`? Don't need to see all, just one that doesn't work. Also provide the docker build and run commands you've issued to get to the `mountpoint for devices not ready`. How did you install the docker engine on your Ubuntu guest?

Comment: what version of docker are you using? `docker version`

Comment: Client version: 1.6.2
Client API version: 1.18
Go version (client): go1.3.3
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.6.2
Server API version: 1.18
Go version (server): go1.3.3
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64

Comment: Can't reproduce that error on my docker 1.8.2 rig. The docker engine is also running on 14.04. `Mountpoint for devices..` implies you're trying to do some kind of host volume mapping when running the container, but this doesn't match with your run example.

Answer (score 0):

Im running ASP.NET 5 in docker on ubuntu 15.04, I noticed in my Dockerfile im using this image:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-rc1-final-coreclr
```

You could try using that image, but it sounds like its your Docker install.

Comment: Well, I just switched a server and everything just worked out of the box. thank you guys for the help.